# Unity2017 WWW Requests fail

Tags: unity

My WWW requests are returning an error that is empty since I switched my project to 2017. Anyone experiencing the same or have a solution?

```
void Start()
  {
    StartCoroutine(RetrieveQuests());
  }

IEnumerator RetrieveQuests() { 
  WWW www; 
  www = new WWW("URL that I dont want to share here."); 
  yield return www; 
  if (www.error != null) { 
    Debug.Log("There was an error sending request: " + www.error); 
  } else { 
    Debug.Log(www.text); 
  } 
}
```

I get the following log when I run it: "There was an error sending request: ", which means www.error is empty but there is an error.

NOTE: This does work on earlier versions of Unity.

Comment: Niels, it would be helpful to see the code you are using.

Comment: I've got a couple of methods that connect to my API to retrieve data. In Unity 5.6.x, they work. They dont work in Unity 2017. I've made this method just to see if WWW requests work at all in Unity 2017:

Comment: I updated the original post.

Comment: Is the url `http` or `https`? And what is the error you are receiving?

Comment: Sorry about that, I used the wrong formatting for code (I'm used to github markdown).

Comment: You should consider switching to UnityWebRequest instead of WWW. It was going to be deprecated, although I'm comparing older documentation with the latest and they may have changed their minds; note the first sentence here https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your check for null might be the issue.
Consider this sample from the Unity script docs:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-error.html

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
        Debug.Log(www.error);
}
```

Comment: Wow. It works.. Why is it that it works when I check it like that? I guess my request always came true but the check always ended up true?

Comment: `If there was no error, error will return null or an empty string (this is because some platforms don't allow nulls for string values).` So it's a cross compatibility thing.

Comment: Ah right. It did work in 5.6.x so I guess that's new then! Thank you very much for your answer.